# Detect what Domain User Group a Windows User is in with VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, usergroups

I know that using Dim currUser As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") returns the Domain\Username, but I want to know what Group that user is in say in Active Directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want a list of the groups?  Or do you want to check if the user is a member of a specific group?

If the latter, you can use WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole() to check if the user belongs to a specific group:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs485fwh.aspx

For example, if you want to check if the user is an Administrator you can use:

```
If Page.User.IsInRole("BUILTIN\Administrators") Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups.aspx)

```
imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
dim name as string = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") 
dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain ), name)
dim groups As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal)= user.GetAuthorizationGroups()
```